# Can I perform aggregations on Google Analytics' data (Direct call to Google Analytics API)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Seems like Google Analytics' metrics are already aggregated in some way. For example, Sessions is already a count of sessions. Visitors is already a count of visitors.

Comment: What is the problem? Please give details.

Comment: You may want to specify some dimension so that you will have a more granular information. I am pretty sure you already have the link, but take a look at the official examples here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples